# Error while writing Spark dataframe to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dataframe, apache-spark

While I'm trying to write from spark to MongoDB using

`MongoSpark.save(df.write.option("collection", "hundredClub").mode("overwrite"))`

The old existing data in MongoDB is not getting overwritten, it remains the same.
While in append mode the data frames rows are appending in MongoDB.

Error while overwriting mode:

`couldn't find collection(hundredClub) using single partition.`

It is not able to find the collection

Comment: Hi Aditya, can you try to write to mongo using a WriteConfig as described here ? https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/java/write-to-mongodb/ (see the second code snippet)

Comment: I want to append data into mongodb. The thing what's happening right now is the data in the old document under the same "_id" is getting replaced by the data under the "_id" in dataframe . I'm using MongoSpark.save(df.write.option("collection", "hundredClub").mode("append"), writeconfig)) and writeconfig has replace document set to false . For example in the main collection I've data as "dog" under _id : 1 now in the dataframe I've "cat" under _id: 1 . When I'm trying to append it , it's showing me output as only "cat" in the main table . "dog" is getting replaced , i tried everything